# pointer segmentation fault with gcc

Tags: c, pointers

```
void main()
{ 
    int *p=20;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
}
```

This code is compiling successfully but giving segmentation fault, I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: Most likely, you do not have permissions to read from memory address 20.

Comment: do you understand what you wrote ? That's why I usually prefer to write "int* p" instead of "int * p" when writing pointer types. To emphasize on the fact that the type is "int*" and not "int".

Comment: this seems to be a common question, this is the third time I've seen it here. note the compiler doesn't check memory for you just translates proper c code to binaries, the compiler AFAIK can't guaranteed the binaries to be safe, since its just a translator.

Answer (score 3):

You defined `p` as a pointer to memory address 20.  You are then trying to dereference that address when you use the `*p` syntax.  Address 20 is unlikely to be in the range of memory you are allowed to access, so it will give you a segmentation fault.

---

`char* i = "abcd";` tells the compiler to set aside space for the string in memory, and point `i` to that place in memory.  You are still assigning the place in memory to the variable.

The `*i` in your `printf` means you want the value which is pointed to by `i`.  In your comment, you won't actually get `abcd`, you will actually get `a`.  This is because `i` points to the first character in the string `"abcd"`, and that character is `a`.

If you want an example of how you can point to integers, take a look at this code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int number = 5;           //A space in memory, set to the value 5
  int* pointer = &number;   //A pointer to point to the space in memory
  printf("%d\n", *pointer); //Using * to get the value pointed to by pointer
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: char *i="abcd";printf("%c\n",*i);
Output is  abcd. why ??

Comment: memory for "abcd" will be allocated in read-only section. so address of "abcd" will be assigned to i.

Comment: This is correct but difference is coming in two cases i did not understand .

Answer (score 3):

I think you are thinking that

```
int *p=20;
```

will stroe an integer value of 20 into pointer P,But its not the case.

you are actually initializing the poinetr value to an address 20.
and in the print statement you are dereferencing it  for which you might not be authorized to do.

try the below code instead

```
void main()
    { 
        int a=20
        int *p=&a;
        printf("%d\n",*p);
    }
```

Comment: char *i="abcd";printf("%c\n",*i); Output is abcd. why ??

Comment: @user1584039 : `char *i="abcd";printf("%c\n",*i);` Output is a

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `p` points to the address `20` which is likely not yours. The `printf` call will try to print the contents of that memory, which is not allowed.